# Android. Определить фрагмент в контейнере

Tags: android, android-fragment

Как определить какой фрагмент в данный момент показан в контейнере?

Если делать так:

```
if (fragmentmanager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.TAG) != null) {}
```

То ответ всегда будет Истина, если мы хоть раз добавили данный фрагмент в стек, даже если фрагмент уже был заменен другим.
И будет Истина пока мы не вызовем remove для данного фрагмента.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать собственный менеджер фрагментов типа:

```
class SimpleFragmentManager  {
        private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        private Stack<Fragment> fragmentStack;

        public SimpleFragmentManager(Activity activity) {
            fragmentManager=activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentStack=new Stack<>();
        }

        public void push(int fragmentContainer, Fragment fragment, String id) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(fragmentContainer, fragment).addToBackStack(id).commit();
            fragmentStack.push(fragment);
        }

        public void reset(int fragmentContainer, Fragment fragment) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
            fragmentStack.empty();
            fragmentStack.push(fragment);
        }

        public Fragment pop() {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            return fragmentStack.pop();
        }

        public Fragment peek() {
            return fragmentStack.peek();
        }

        public int size() {
            return fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        }

        public void addOnBackStackChangedListener(FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener listener) {
            fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(listener);
        }
    }
```

Тогда текущие фрагмент всегда можно получить через `peek()`

Answer (score 0):

Вам стоит следить за fragment.TAG чтобы для разных фрагментов он был разный. И стоит использовать replace вместо add во время добавления фрагмента.